# Como apresentar várias variáveis em um único print em Java

Tags: java, python

Estou aprendendo Java depois de já ter feito o curso inteiro de Python do Curso em Vídeo e como recém estou começando, tive um dúvida.
Como que eu posso mostrar múltiplas variáveis em um único print em Java, desde modo como eu faria em Python:

```
nome = 'Pedro'
idade = 16
print(f'Olá {nome}, voce tem {idade} anos!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

string ***variavelnome*** = "Pedro";

int ***idade*** = 20;

System.out.print("Olá " + ***variavelnome*** + " Você Tem: " + ***idade*** + " Anos.");

Em Java separa variável de strings através do comando de atribuição +.

Caso for fazer uma operação, colocar a operação entre parenteses. ;)